# Converting/Exporting to libgdx G3D

Tags: java, libgdx, export, blender, fbx

I have been trying for a very long time to convert files to G3D, the only success I had is drag-and-drop files on the [fbx-conv](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/fbx-conv/).

I understood there is a exporter for blender, even a way to convert fbx in code...
I can't make any of them to work, can someone help me with a very precise tutorial or step by step instructions?

At the [building section](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv) I did as it said, I tried all that I could think of but to no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G3D file format is deprecated and replaced by the G3DJ and G3DB file format. FBX-Conv can be used to convert FBX (and other file formats) to either a g3dj or g3db file. As far as I know there is no exporter directly to g3dj/b for blender yet, instead export to FBX and then convert using fbx-conv. Fbx-conv is a command line utility. If you are unfamiliar with command line utilities, you might want to search the internet for some information on running those on your operating system. Run fbx-conv without arguments to see all possible options.

A tutorial you might be interested in: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/

Comment: I didn't know there was a G3D format in the past , i thought that G3D was a way of saying G3DB/G3DJ . I was hoping of a more explicit way to install fbx-conv , I did everything on the git wiki , got premake4 , updated VC 2010 , made a FBX_SDK_ROOT variable and setting it to the sdk , etc. but no matter what it doesn't recognize fbx-conv as a command ( i'm using windows ) . Like i said , now i'm converting to g3db by drag-and-drop , but I wanted to convert to g3dj so i can see how and what information of a shape is stored .

Comment: You don't have to *build* fbx-conv, just download the prebuild binaries (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/fbx-conv). So no need to get premake, vc, fbx sdk, etc. Download the binaries and extract them to a location accessible from the command line (the zip contains the binaries for all platforms, you only need to extract the one for your platform, e.g. fbx-conv-win32.exe).

Comment: I managed to make it work , feeling really stupid , i was typing fbx-conv in the cmd , not realizing you had to put the name of the file in there ...

Answer (score 3):

There is an addon for Blender that exports directly to .g3dj format.

Check this link for info on setting it up:

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/02/26/Exporting-3D-model-to-LibGDX-directly-from-Blender.aspx